# Symfony3 - Display image with database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I would like to display an image which is in my database. But I have error:

> "Unrecognized field: name"

I made a entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
    
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $title;
 
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $description;
    
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="blob", nullable=true)
 */
private $image;
    
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $dataStart;
  
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $dataEnd;
```

And this is my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/promotion",
 *      name = "pizza_promotion"
 * )
 * 
 * @Template
 */
public function promotionAction() {
       
    $RepoPromotion = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PizzaBundle:Promotion');
        
    $rowsPromotion = $RepoPromotion->findAll();
    $rowsImage = $RepoPromotion->findBy(array('name' => 'image'));
      
    if(!empty($rowsImage)) {
        $respons = base64_decode($rowsImage);
    }
        
    return array(
        'rowsPromotion' => $rowsPromotion,
        'respons' => $respons
    );
}
```

But when I want display image with my twig

```
{% for entry in response %}
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ entry.image }}" alt="HTML5 Icon"> zł</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I have error - "Unrecognized field: name"

Comment: $RepoPromotion->findBy(array('name' => 'image')); can't work. You have to set a key/value in the array like array("image" => 1). But I think that you have to use your $rowsPromotion variable in your twig template to get all your images

Comment: Yes, of course. But if I used 

{% for entry in rowsPromotion %} 
<tr>
                                        <td>
                                          <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ entry.image }}">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
I have not display image only this I have "Resource id #939" this is value in database. Probably I must use base64 decode, but twig have not a filter base64. Therefore I must download this value in controller and use base64 but this way i'm not leaving.

Comment: If you have some troubles with encode and decode I suggest you to use https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle. It will be easier to manage images

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your find:

```
$rowsImage = $RepoPromotion->findBy(array('name' => 'image'));
```

Based on your entity you likely want:

```
$rowsImage = $RepoPromotion->findBy(array('title' => 'image'));
```

But basically it is saying that your Promotion repo doesnt have a property `name` to search by.